# Change UIButton state in Prototype Cell in Storyboard

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, ipad

I have two buttons in Prototype Cell in storyboard.  One for IBAction and the other for IBOutlet.  Then subclass the UITableViewCell to MyTableViewCell and point it to Prototype Cell in storyboard.  Then I control+drag the action button to MyTableViewCell to create a IBAction and do the same for the outlet button to create a IBOutlet.

In the method:

```
  -(void)buttonPress:(UIButton *)sender
  {
      MyTableViewCell *cell = (MyTableViewCell *)[[sender superview] superview];
      cell.outletButton.selected = YES;
      ...
  }
```

I get the error message:

reason: '-[UITableViewCellScrollView outletButton]: unrecognized selector sent to instance

What I am doing wrong?  What I try to do is to have two buttons in Prototype Cell.  When one button is pressed, the other button can change the state to show background images, such as selected or highlighted.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

On iOS6 and earlier your code seems fine, but on iOS 7 you have to do one more step of `superview` if you want to get to the cell. So it will be:

```
MyTableViewCell *cell = (MyTableViewCell *)[[[sender superview] superview] superview];
```

Comment: thank.  after the change, there is no error message, but the state still doesn't have.  It alway is normal state and wouldn't change to selected state.

Comment: You should not change the state of your button, but set e.g. a different background image, if you want to customize the appearance. You could try the `highlighted` property (maybe it will work), but I would rather do the image change

Comment: thanks again.  Yes, I set different background image for selected and highlighted property, but when set cell.button.selected = YES, the state doesn't change.

Comment: Instead of the line `cell.button.selected = YES`, change the image you have for normal state.

Answer (score 0):

It's usually not a good idea to navigate the view hierarchy in this way, as you've found, there can be differences between OS versions that can break your code.

If your IBAction and IBOutlet are both connected to your MyTableViewCell class, you can simply use:

```
- (void)buttonPress:(UIButton *)sender
{
  self.outletButton.selected = YES;
  ...
}
```

You will also want to implement `prepareForReuse:` in MyTableViewCell to stop the properties of the buttons becoming copied when the cell is reused.